# How to show selected dates in Highlight using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#datepicker').datepicker({
               dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy', 
               onSelect: function() { 
               $("#getDate").click(function () {
    var start = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate"),
    currentDate = new Date(start),
    between = [];
    for(var i=0;i<7;i++) {
        currentDate.setTime(currentDate.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000);
                                        //miliseconds in 1 day
        between.push(new Date(currentDate));

    }
     for (var i = 0; i < between.length; i++) {
        var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date(between[i]));
        between[i] = date;
         $('#datepicker').datepicker({

        beforeShowDay: function(date) {

            var Highlight = between[i];
            if (Highlight) {
                return [true, "Highlighted", Highlight];
            }
            else {
                return [true, '', ''];
            }
        }
    });


    }
        $.getJSON('http://localhost:10039/wps/wcm/myconnect/SampleWork/SampleWork_SA/?srv=cmpnt&source=library&cmpntname=CalendarMenu', function (data) {
    console.log("Length!!!"  +data.length);    
            $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            console.log("Date!!!!!"  +val.Date);
                if(between[i] = val.Date){
                    console.log("In If Block");
                   // console.log("EventName: " +val.EventName);
                console.log("EventName!!!" +val.EventName);
                $(".current").append("<table cellspacing='5' cellpadding='5'><tr><td>" + val.Time +"  " + "</td><td>"+"  " + val.EventName +"  " + "</td><td>"+"  " + val.EventDescription +"</td><td>" + '<img class="meeting" src="http://localhost:10039' + val.Image + '" alt="" />' +"</td></tr></table>");    
                }
            });
        });

    console.log("Date : "+between);
    //Here I am Getting : Date : 08/05/2014,08/06/2014,08/07/2014,08/08/2014,08/09/2014,08/10/2014,08/11/2014 

})


               }                
           });
       });
```

css is :

```
.Highlighted a{

       background-color : Green !important;

       background-image :none !important;

       color: White !important;

       font-weight:bold !important;

       font-size: 12pt;

    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It's great to see the code, but please formulate a question for us to answer other than what you provided in the title.

Comment: Autaully  here i am getting Date like what i mention in comment line,These dates should  be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the class which is being used to select date that is 'ui-state-active' and then have your desired color and formatting over there

```
.ui-state-active {
    background: red !important;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t2bd51aj/)

As per the comment here is the updated answer:

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t2bd51aj/3/)

Code snippet:

```
var SelectedDates = {};
SelectedDates[new Date('08/08/2014')] = new Date('08/08/2014');
SelectedDates[new Date('08/09/2014')] = new Date('08/09/2014');
SelectedDates[new Date('08/10/2014')] = new Date('08/10/2014');
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var Highlight = SelectedDates[date];
            if (Highlight) {
                return [true, "Highlighted", Highlight];
            }
            else {
                return [true, '', ''];
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks For your Reply,Actaully i want in that datepicker it will show red color,Here what u did, mean after clicking the particular date ,it is showing red color.My Problem is that,in that between array no of dates are there.Automatic this dates has to show in red color,Not after clicking the date

Comment: Yeah I did this one ,itz working Perfect,why because its static date,but in my app all are dyanamic dates,not able to show these dates .

Comment: you can loop in your dates and create new Date objects it should work you can make a fiddle for the same

Comment: In My previous code , i had applied,but not working,Can u please Find the Solution

Comment: Can you try to make a jsfiddle for your problem you can reuse the fiddle I created and create your response array in SelectedDates

Comment: Here i have Created Nee Date Object Right that Is Between

Comment: you would have to upvote and then mark as an answer for this one :-)